# PouchDB allDocs() total_rows differs from number of all docs returned

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm iterating through all docs in a pouchdb-database. To get all docs, I'm using `result = await db.info()` with that I read `result.doc_count`. I'm getting 961 docs. Same 961 docs with `db.allDocs() total_rows`. The weird thing is, the actual returned rows from `db.allDocs() total_rows` returns an array with 1.328 docs.

`{total_rows: 961, offset: 0, rows: Array(1328)}`

So when I use the value of 961 I'm missing lots of docs.

I also use auto compaction so the difference shouldn't be from deleted docs, also tried to compact before reading with no change to those values.

Why this behaviour?

Thank you!

P.S.: This behaviour is only after a bulkdocs operation.

Comment: That PS seems very relevant, can you edit your question to include that detail please. Perhaps showing an example of before the bulk docs operation where the counts match, and then after when they don't?